# How to run a program, redirect its output and display the output on the screen?

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, io-redirection, executable

doing this in bash script
`./Execute_program > MyOutput`
I get a log file from the output, however this causes the output not to be displayed on the terminal screen. Is there any way to do the same but at the same time the output can be displayed on the screen?

Comment: `program | tee myoutput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the universal pipe fitting, `tee`.  `tee` reads input, and duplicates the output to both standard output and the specified file:

```
./Execute_program | tee MyOutput
```

If you want to *append to* rather than *overwrite* the specified file, use `-a`:

```
./Execute_program | tee -a MyOutput
```

If you want to write to several files, just add them as additional parameters:

```
./Execute_program | tee MyOutput MyOtherSavedLog
```